# A problem with kendodatepicker over https

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use kendodatepicker in my asp mvc project for input persian date.But when publish my website over https . Https not allow to load kendo cdn.This is my console log :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gormast.ir/Admin/Discount/Create' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.default.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gormast.ir/Admin/Discount/Create' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.common.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gormast.ir/Admin/Discount/Create' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gormast.ir/Admin/Discount/Create' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.default.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gormast.ir/Admin/Discount/Create' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.common.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Use the https version. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/cdn-service#use-the-https

Comment: i already did it but it didnt work

Comment: Are you bundling or directly linking?

Comment: directly linking